# How to allow a user to create databases only with a certain prefix?

Tags: postgresql, users

We're having a multi-user Linux server. I'd like to give each user the ability to create and manage databases at will, but to keep things sane, force them that each database name they create must start with their user name as prefix. For example, user `joe` would be only allowed to create databases like `joe_app1` and `joe_app2` but not `app1` or `jack_app1`. Is this possible in PostgreSQL? Or is there another way how to separate name-spaces for user-created databases?

Comment: Why not give every user only one database and let them use schemas to separate the name spaces?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, that would be an option, but since our users work on different projects and they need to backup/restore their respective databases separately, it could make things a bit complicated for them.

Comment: You can't really do this inside PostgreSQL.  However, I imagine you could set up a script (with the appropriate ownership and permissions) which can create new DBs, checking the prefix first.  It should then set the ownership of the DB as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not allow you to do this inside PostgreSQL.  You cannot create a database inside a transaction so procedural language functions cannot create databases or drop databases.  I hope some day this is corrected, but it is the one piece of DDL that does not work inside a transaction.

What this means is you have to do it from outside the database with a separate application that runs whatever checks you want to run.  Some key things to keep in mind are:

1. You probably want to have a dedicated user (role with `login`, `noinherit`) for the database creation process.
2. You do not want to give the permission to create dbs to the general users.
3. The script should create the database and then `ALTER DATABASE ... OWNER TO ...` in order to ensure that the user has full permissions to it.

Comment: +1 as this is the answer I was lazy to write :)  On the other hand, I see the `CREATE/DROP DATABASE` exception a quite logical choice.  Encasing it in a transaction could raise quite a few interesting effects.

Comment: I am not sure how the side effects would be much more unmanageable than with `drop table` or `drop user` both of which can be rolled back.  I don't know why one couldn't wait until commit to do essentially an rm -rf and block connections in the mean time.